# Why doesn't cURL send expires/max-age value of cookie back to server ?

Tags: java, curl, cookies, netty

I am building a server using Netty.io framework in java and I am facing a problem in authenticating requests.

While authenticating the request, I am trying to validate it by checking **sessionId** and it's **expiry**.

```
if (sessionId == correctSessionId && expiry < currentTime) {
   // then mark the request as authenticated.
}
```

But whenever I send a request to server (After i have logged in and received proper cookies with expiry), there is not expiry/max-age received at server end. What am I doing wrong ?

Curl request for Logging in:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/account/login -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"mobile": "123", "password": "123"}' -v
```

Output:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/account/login HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 36
>
* upload completely sent off: 36 out of 36 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Replaced cookie sessionId="efB9DYHl46aARJMtW59fSKuf+wVtpZ0Y0eveJiLMLH+lEBfvHjzaow==" for domain localhost, path /api/v1/account/, expire 1469968200
< Set-Cookie: sessionId=efB9DYHl46aARJMtW59fSKuf+wVtpZ0Y0eveJiLMLH+lEBfvHjzaow==; Max-Age=180; Expires=Sun, 31 Jul 2016 12:30:00 GMT
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
<
* Closing connection 0
{"id":"579d3d9902dd1134817edefc","name":"admin","mobile":"123","email":null,"audit":{"createdTime":1469922712940,"createdBy":null,"modifiedTime":1469922712940,"modifiedBy":null}}
```

> Notice Set-cookie header and it's expiry date. Server sends it correctly.

Cookies.txt file:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

localhost FALSE /api/v1/account/  FALSE 1469968200  sessionId efB9DYHl46aARJMtW59fSKuf+wVtpZ0Y0eveJiLMLH+lEBfvHjzaow==
```

> cookies.text also stores the values correctly.

Curl request for accessing a resource that requires authentication:

```
curl -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -XGET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/account/details -H 'content-type: application/json' -v
```

And it's output:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/v1/account/details HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: sessionId=efB9DYHl46aARJMtW59fSKuf+wVtpZ0Y0eveJiLMLH+lEBfvHjzaow==
> content-type: application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
<
* Closing connection 0
Session Unauthorized. Please login%
```

> SessionId is sent but no expiry or max-age. Why ?

What am I missing out ?

Comment: Why do the client need to send the expiration date? The server should have the expiration date stored for the session and compare that to the current time, not whatever information the client is sending. Never trust the client!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curl doesn't send that back because it follows the HTTP cookie protocol (see [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)) and it says a client should only send the `name=val` for each cookie. The expire time and other meta-data is sent by the server and dealt with by the client, but they are never sent back.